# Possible textbook error

Tags: calculus

According to my textbook, splitting the following equation into partial fractions:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{kx(x+20)}{100}$$

$$\frac{dx}{x(x+20)} = \frac{kdt}{100}$$

becomes

$$\frac{dx}{x}-\frac{dx}{x+20} = \frac{k}{5}dt$$

Is this correct ??

Comment: Yes, it is a correct step. The calculation, which "separates" the $dx$ and the $dt$, is on the informal side, but traditional in first courses.

Comment: 1/x - 1/(x+20) = [x+20 -x]/x (x+20) = 20/x (x+20) ... so, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, because
$$
\frac1x -\frac1{x+20} = \frac{20}{x(x+20)}
$$
after finding a common denominator for the two fractions on the LHS.

Comment: You can use partial fractions to check that this is indeed true @Murdock

Comment: Thanks guys ! Still struggling but guess have to go back - WAY back !!

Comment: Did check it @K.Power !! Just struggled with the minus sign. And then the k/5 ??

Comment: Now I need to integrate on the right side between t = 0 and t after 2 hours. On the right side I need to integrate between 30gr of chemical added initially and 20gr dissolved after 2 hours on BOTH the terms, to determine the dissolving constant k ??

Comment: Ask a new question for that and give more details on the question, also show your attempts. Also give mathjax a look and learn how we typeset maths here at MSE, you'll attract a lot more interest in your questions that way.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{kx(x+20)}{100}$$
$$\frac{dx}{x(x+2)}=\frac{k}{100}dt$$ Now from the below answer we know that $$\frac{dx}{x(x+2)}=\frac{dx}{20}\bigg(\frac1x -\frac1{x+20}\bigg)$$ and so putting this all together $$dx\bigg(\frac1x -\frac1{x+20}\bigg) =\frac{20k}{100}dt$$